# How do I group rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is what I have tried and the result I would like to achieve. I am using jupyter to execute this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})

df
```

output:

```
  a  b
0 A  1
1 A  2
2 B  5
3 B  5
4 B  4
5 C  6
```

Further I tried:

```
s = df[['a','b']].groupby(df['a']).sum()

     b
a
A    3
B    14
C    6
```

This is similar to what I wanted in terms of grouping the rows but I dont understand why the label b was way up, should it not be in the same line as a?
Also, when I iterate through `s` I only get `b` and when I iterate thorough `a['b']` I get all the quantities. However, I want all the letters say iterate over `s['a']` and get `A,B,C` but this throws an error. Thanks

Comment: `s = df[['a','b']].groupby(df['a']).sum().reset_index()`?

Comment: `df.groupby('a',as_index=False).b.sum()
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [15]: df.groupby('a').sum().reset_index()
Out[15]:
   a   b
0  A   3
1  B  14
2  C   6
```